# How to port forward using Windows Firewall in Windows 7 (1194->53)

Tags: windows-firewall, port-forwarding

Hi I haven't been able to find solid information about how to do this.

I have a VPN in my home server and at work they have blocked the OpenVPN port 1194, how can I have my windows 7 use another port when it tries to go out port 1194? i.e. port 53 or port 443

I think I've found this is done with firewalls, and I've found information on doing it with iptables but how about doing it on Windows Firewall or another windows based firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your OpenVPN server to listen on 443, and configure the client to connect to 443.
It might also be worth setting the protocol to TCP, as UDP on 443 might be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

No it is just a firewall, it doesn't do NAT or port forwarding.  However there are 3rd party port forwarding apps for windows that are googleable.